# "private method `new' called for Message:Class"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code in my messages_controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @message = Message.new
    end

  def create
    @message = Message.new message_params

    if @message.valid?
      MessageMailer.contact_me(@message).deliver_now
      redirect_to new_message_url, notice: "Message received, thanks!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

 private

 def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:name, :email, :body)
  end  
end
```

But I keep getting the error "private method 'new' called for Message:Class." whenever I attempt to load the page that displays the message form (route: /messages/new). New is not a private method as far as I can tell? Any help would be appreciated in this error!

My mailer class looks like this:

```
class Message < ApplicationMailer

  def contact_me(message)
    @body = message.body

    mail to: "EMAIL@gmail.com", from: message.email
  end
end
```

EDIT:
I have included my message model

```
class Message
    include ActiveModel::Model
    attr_accessor :name, :email, :body
    validates :name, :email, :body, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Paste your Message model please.

Comment: Ok, your message is not an AR model, is a mailer, new for ActionMailer is private, take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html for correct ActionMailer usage.

Comment: You named your mailer `Message < ApplicationMailer` and then try to use it as `MessageMailer.contact_me` in your controller. You now have the class `Message` opened in 2 places (as a model and a mailer) with different parent classes and are having weirdness. Fixing the typo in the class declaration (change `Message < ApplicationMailer` to `MessageMailer < ApplicationMailer` as you apparently intended to name it should fix it)

Comment: @SimpleLime thank you so much, that solved it!!!